# How to extract the entire matching group in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have some data's like `2014-06-11T22:22:17`

which i am matching using regex `([\d-])+T([\d:])+` in two different part by separating date and time like

`2014-06-11` and  `22:22:17` so i have created two groups

but when i am extracting the data like as below

```
Date =m.group(1);
```

it extract only digit "1" in Date String, why is it not extracting the entire group which is `2014-06-11`?

Comment: You have to repeat the character class instead of the capturing group. `[\d-]+` Repeating the group will give you the value of the last iteration, and findall will return the group which will then contain a single value.

Comment: Why not write the whole pattern? `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to use `LocalDateTime` in your case to get the date and time separately like this :

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2014-06-11T22:22:17");
LocalDate date = dateTime.toLocalDate(); // 2014-06-11
LocalTime time = dateTime.toLocalTime(); // 22:22:17
```